Querying a whole graph emulated with SQL Server tables
I have an SQL-Server 2019 database with 2 tables NODE and EDGE, where NODE consists of two columns ID (int) and NAME (varchar)
and EDGE consists of two columns PARENTELEMENTID (int) and CHILDELEMENTID(int).
With the help of these two tables I'm now able to emulate a graph structure inside my relational database. For Example:
    CREATE TABLE NODE(ID int, NAME varchar(1));
    CREATE TABLE EDGE(PARENTELEMENTID int, CHILDELEMENTID int);

    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(1, 'A');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(2, 'B');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(3, 'C');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(4, 'D');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(5, 'E');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(6, 'F');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(7, 'G');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(8, 'H');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(9, 'I');
    INSERT INTO NODE (Id, Name) VALUES(10, 'J');

    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (1, 4);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (1, 5);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (2, 4);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (2, 6);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (3, 7);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (4, 7);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (5, 8);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (6, 9);
    INSERT INTO EDGE (ParentElementId, ChildElementId) VALUES (10, 9);

That result in the following Graph:

What I need is a statement to retrieve all nodes in this graph, starting at any node.
My first attempt was the following statement:
    WITH ElementsToGetParentsFrom as (
        select n.Id
        from NODE n
        where n.Id in (1)
    ),
    ParentHierachies AS (
        SELECT p.Id,
               0 as traceLevel,
               NEWID() as TraceId
        from ElementsToGetParentsFrom p
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            e.ParentElementId as id,
            ph.traceLevel + 1,
            ph.TraceId as TraceId
        FROM EDGE e
        JOIN ParentHierachies ph ON e.ChildElementId = ph.id
    ),
    GetRootIds as (
        select ph.Id,
               dense_rank() over (partition by TraceId order by traceLevel desc) as ranking
        from ParentHierachies ph
    ),
    AllElementsInGraph as (
        select gri.Id as Id
        from GetRootIds gri
        where gri.ranking = 1
        union all
        select e.ChildElementId as Id
        from EDGE e
        join AllElementsInGraph aeit on aeig.Id = e.ParentElementId
    )
    SELECT N.*
    FROM AllElementsInGraph aeig
    INNER JOIN NODE N on aeig.Id = N.Id

I'm using the first cte 'ElementsToGetParentsFrom' as an entrance for my statement to decide of which nodes I want to retrieve the graphs.
The second cte 'ParentHierachies' traverses the graph(s) upwards from the given node(s), giving them a level (used for next cte) and a trace-id, to be able to differ between the different root elements.
Now the third cte 'GetRootIds' uses the traceid and tracelevel to reduce the result to only root elements of the graphs by partitioning all id's by their traceid and ranking them by their level in the graph.
In the last cte 'AllElementsInGraph' I'm traversing down from the RootElements to get all Nodes in the graph.
The statement works only if my graph is more like a tree (I think there is my problem, since while I'm writing this, I'm realising I'm mixing up terms for trees and graphs).
So for my example graph I'm getting the following results for this input:
A -> A,D,E,G,H
B -> B,E,F,H,I
C -> C,G
D -> A,D,E,G,H
E -> A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I
F -> B,E,F,H,I
G -> A,C,D,E,G,H
H -> A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I
I -> B,E,F,H,I,J
J -> I,J

What I need is a statement (if it is even possible), to retrieve all nodes, given any node(s).
A -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
B -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
C -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
D -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
E -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
F -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
G -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
H -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
I -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
J -> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J


What do you want to output if your data contains several disjoint graphs ?

@p3consulting if i'm providing nodes from several disjoint graphs i'd like to get all nodes of all the graphs my provided nodes are in.

A single SELECT query is problematic if you want to handle arbitrary levels of recursion.
Here's an version based on a looping approach.
create table #n (id int not null primary key)

declare @start varchar(10)
set @start = 'A'

insert into #n (id) select id from node where name = @start

while @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN

; with nodes (id) as 
    (select ParentElementId from EDGE where ChildElementId in (select id from #n) 
    union all
    select ChildElementid from EDGE where ParentElementid in (select id from #n))

insert into #n (id) select distinct id from nodes where id not in (select id from #n)

END

select * from #n


Thanks for your answer. I'll try and update my answer. Can you maybe elaborate on it performancewise in contrary to a single-select-query and if there are any risks when working with temp tables?

Try this one:
with cte(ParentElementId, ChildElementId) as (
    select ParentElementId, ChildElementId from edge
    where ParentElementId = @startId or ChildElementId = @startId
    
    union all

    select e.ParentElementId, e.ChildElementId
    from cte c
    join edge e
    on 
        c.ParentElementId = e.ChildElementId 
        or c.ChildElementId = e.ParentElementId
        or c.ParentElementId = e.ParentElementId
        or c.ChildElementId = e.ChildElementId
)
cycle ParentElementId, ChildElementId set is_cycle to 1 default 0
select ParentElementId as Id from cte
union 
select ChildElementId from cte
order by Id
;


Thanks for your answer. As far as i know the cycle keyword is an oracle exclusive keyword, can you provide an example with sql-server 2019?

oops sorry, I thought they added it in recent releases... solutions how to detect cycles in recursive CTE in SQLServer should be easy to find on the net
